# Get "shares" from an application's post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, share, status

I have a big problem when I try to retrieve the number of shares from a post.
I give you the steps to reproduce my problem.

1. Share a post on a user timeline through an application like "Javascript Test Console" using this code:

   `<script>
   FB.ui({
     method: 'feed',
     link: 'http://www.pxly.it',
     name: 'PXLY',
     caption: 'web and app development',
     description: 'Sviluppiamo applicazioni virali Facebook e mobile, siti web responsive, giochi e grafiche personalizzate.'
   }, function(response){
     if (response && !response.error) {
       alert("post_id: "+response.post_id);
     }
   });
   </script>`
2. Now you have a post_id like this: "post_id: 1344530438_10204137339017433".
3. Open the "Graph API Explorer" and give the read_stream permission.
4. Go on your timeline and share the post.
5. Now if you try to retrieve the number of shares (that should be 1), you cannot have it.
   Try with GET /{post_id}/shares:

   `GET/1344530438_10204137339017433/shares`

   or GET /{second_part_of_post_id}/sharedposts:

   `GET/10204137339017433/sharedposts`

   or GET/[post_id]?summary=1.
6. I always get no answer.

This is a bug?
Why I cannot have this number of shares?
The post is an "app_created_story" type status. This is the problem?

Because if you share the second post and try to retrieve the number of shares of it, you can do it!

Please, help me!
I hope someone have the answer.

Thank you!

Edit: I think that is a bug https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1460378860850862/